# Adding TTF font to a phar for use by GD imagettftext

Tags: php, gd, phar

I have just started playing with phar to make deploying a library of files easier. One of the functions is a captcha code creator that uses GD to make a PNG file. The text on the image comes from a TTF file using imatettftext. I have compiled all of the php scripts into a single phar archive and it works perfectly, except the captcha.

I understand that the GD library handles its own filesystem access for fonts, but does this mean I have to have the tff as a separate file to the phar? It would be more than handy to have all the required resources in the single archive.

Alternatively, if GD cannot access the font from the archive, is there a different/better way to put text on an image for use in a captcha that can be compiled into the phar?

Answer (score 2):

GD cannot access anything in phar archive, so you need to copy your TTF font outside of the phar to allow GD reach it.